# Can a .NET object actually have no constructors, according to reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm writing a really simple IoC/DI container, and I've got the following code:

```
ConstructorInfo[] ctors = concreteType.GetConstructors();

if (ctors.Length == 0)
    return Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType);

// more code goes here...
```

I can't come up with a test case that results in a type having zero constructors, even with this:

```
class LonelyType {}
```

Is it possible for a .NET type to have *no* constructors, or does the CLR always provide an implicit one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - static classes have no constructors:

```
static class VeryLonelyType{}
```

The normal parameterless constructor is provided by the *C# compiler*, not the CLR.

Note that as far as the CLR is concerned, structs generated from C# don't have parameterless constructors either. For example:

```
struct Foo{}
```

won't contain a parameterless constructor. You *can* do it in IL, which can [prove interesting](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx)...